# Oracle query to pivot rows info into columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores information about opening and closing times for a branch as follows:

```
LOCATION   DAYOFTHEWEEK OPENORCLOSE       TIME
---------- ------------ ----------- ----------
AUSTIN         SUN       Open              1730
AUSTIN         MON       Close              200
AUSTIN         MON       Open               830
AUSTIN         TUE       Close              200
AUSTIN         TUE       Open               830
AUSTIN         WED       Close              200
AUSTIN         WED       Open               830
AUSTIN         THU       Close              200
AUSTIN         THU       Open               830
AUSTIN         FRI       Close              200
AUSTIN         FRI       Open               830
AUSTIN         FRI       Close             1730
```

As you can see, not all days have necessarily an open/close day and a single day can have multiple open/close times, the reason being that a branch may open the previous day, work a night shift and then close the next day. In this example, the Austin branch opens Sunday at 5:30 pm, closes Monday at 2:00 am, and then reopens at 8:30 to work all the way to the next day again until 2:00 am. On Fridays, they close at 5:30 pm, have Saturday off and then open again on Sunday to repeat the same cycle.

My question is, could it be possible using a select statement alone to return rows that looks something like this:

```
LOCATION   DAYOFTHEWEEK   OPENTIME  CLOSETIME
---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
AUSTIN           SUN          1730       null    
AUSTIN           MON          null       200
AUSTIN           MON          830        null
AUSTIN           TUE          null       200
AUSTIN           TUE          830        null
AUSTIN           WED          null       200
AUSTIN           WED          830        null
AUSTIN           THU          null       200
AUSTIN           THU          830        null
AUSTIN           FRI          null       200
AUSTIN           FRI          830       1730
```

null is just a placeholder, any value like -1, or whatever would work too. Time in this particular case is an int value that represents a time equivalence (200 for 2:00 am, 1730 for 17:30, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will solve your problem

```
select location,dayoftheweek,
       case openorclose when 'Open' then time end "OPENSTATUS",
       case openorclose when 'Close' then time end "CLOSESTATUS" from YOUR_TABLE;
```

[**LIVE SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8de80/15)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
select location,dayofweek,
case when openorclose = 'Open' then time end as OpenTime,
case when openorclose = 'CLOSE' then time end as CloseTime
from TableName;
```